# How do I correctly use a while-loop to fill 2 Arraylists with user input?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to first input a name(string) and then an amount(double) and puts the input into 2 seperate Arraylists. This is done through a while-loop. When the user is done, they can press 0 and then program will print both arraylists. 
The first time through the loop goes perfect, the second time it will print both lines asking for input without allowing input in between. When given an input the second time it will show a InputMismachtException.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> customerName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> customerSpend = new ArrayList<>();
double checkUserInput = 1;

while (checkUserInput != 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer name");
    customerName.add(userInput.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer amount");
    customerSpend.add(userInput.nextDouble());
    if (customerSpend.get(customerSpend.size()-1) == 0){
        checkUserInput = 0;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < customerName.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(customerName.get(i)+customerSpend.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextDouble()` reads only the token in line and will not read the complete line. so when the `nextLine()` is executed it will read the remaining line and the `name` you entered in console will be read by `nextDouble()` and that throws `InputMismachtException`

> Scans the next token of the input as a double.

So to avoid this you can use `nextLine()` and parse the value into `Double`

You can use `nextLine()` and parse the value into `Double`

```
while (checkUserInput != 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer name");
    customerName.add(userInput.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter the customer amount");
    customerSpend.add(Double.parseDouble(userInput.nextLine()));

    if (customerSpend.get(customerSpend.size()-1) == 0){
        checkUserInput = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, had to change the `customerSpend.add(Double.parseDouble(userInput.nextDouble()));` to `customerSpend.add(Double.parseDouble(userInput.nextLine()));`, but you got me there!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Scanner.nextDouble method does not read the newline character in your input created by hitting "Enter," and so the call to Scanner.nextLine returns after reading that newline.

You will encounter the similar behaviour when you use Scanner.nextLine after Scanner.next() or any Scanner.nextFoo method (except nextLine itself).

**What i suggest is to call an extra userInput.nextLine() right after you call userInput.nextDouble() in order to read that extraline.**